# Не получается сделать downgrade PHP с 7.2 на 5.5 (CentOS 6)

Tags: php, centos, ssh

не получается понизить версию PHP, вчера обновился до 7.2, но сегодня решил обратно.

Выполняю так:

```
#wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
#wget http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
#rpm -Uvh remi-release-6.rpm epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
#yum install yum-utils
#yum-config-manager --enable remi-php55
#yum-config-manager --disable remi-php72
#yum update -y
```

Получаю:

```
Загружены модули: fastestmirror, security
Подготовка к обновлению
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.awanti.com
 * epel: epel.mirror.far.fi
 * extras: mirror.awanti.com
 * remi: mirror.awanti.com
 * remi-php55: mirror.awanti.com
 * remi-safe: mirror.awanti.com
 * remi-test: mirror.awanti.com
 * updates: mirror.awanti.com
remi                                                     | 3.0 kB     00:00     
remi-debuginfo                                           | 3.0 kB     00:00     
remi-php55                                               | 3.0 kB     00:00     
remi-php55-debuginfo                                     | 3.0 kB     00:00     
remi-php56-debuginfo                                     | 3.0 kB     00:00     
remi-test                                                | 3.0 kB     00:00     
remi-test-debuginfo                                      | 3.0 kB     00:00     
Нет пакетов, отмеченных для обновления
```

Что делать? Сайт повис на php7, нужно много правок вносить, поэтому нужно срочно скинуть до 5.

Comment: Вариант сначала удалить (через `yum remove`) php72 и потом установить php55  - не рассматривали?

Comment: @nobody сейчас попробую, использовать yum remove -y php72?

Comment: Лично я бы сначала сохранил список пакетов куда-нибудь (`rpm -qa > /tmp/pkts.txt`) затем сохранил бы конфиги куда-то (скорее всего они в `/etc/opt/remi/php72/`, но у Вас может быть другой путь) и только потом удалял что-то и устанавливал другую версию